# Installing editable library with pip works in commandline python but not jupyter

Tags: python-3.x, pip, jupyter

I'm installing a library (let's call it `my_library`) with `pip install -e .` from the library's top level directory. I've done this on multiple other machines without issue.
But, on one machine I have a problem:

`from my_library import config` works fine when I use python in the terminal window, but the same import doesn't work from inside a jupyter notebook.

This is something I've not seen before, does anyone have ideas as to what could be the problem?